# Python csv to xlsx with specified conditions

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, xlsx

Well, I am trying to make a script in python that suppose to convert csv files to xlsx. For this moment I just want to make one xlsx from my csv file. I have this part of code and works fine:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')): 
 workbook = Workbook(os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0] + '.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
       reader=csv.reader((f), delimiter=",")
       for r, row in enumerate(reader):
           for c, col in enumerate(row):
               worksheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```

But, the problem is that this script turns all cells into the text. 
I need **that she format cells which are numbers as numbers and other cells that are not number to format as text**. Does anyone knows how to write that condition?
Please help me, I'm realy stacked with this a long time...

Comment: Why not do this as a VBA macro? And what do you mean by *"xlsx but with csv extension"*?!

Comment: Well, there is some problems with date... And in future I ll have a lot of csv files... Script will be faster solution, don't you think? Well about extension, they are saved as test.csv after script but when I open it I see that is converted to xlsx

Comment: Ok, this script is ok, but problem is with saving files... Why he save file with csv extension, but he changes type and icon as xlsx?

Comment: If you have the `csv` extension associated with Excel, the files will have an Excel-style icon and will be opened by Excel (which displays it like a spreadsheet) - this doesn't affect the content. You can check by opening the file with a text editor like Notepad++.

Comment: I solve this workbook = Workbook('test.xlsx') so it is ok... But I need to open folder with all that csv files and convert them automatically, I ve tried smth like this but it is not ok, do you know or have some suggestion?

Comment: What help did you think an unformatted code dump and the frankly useless problem description *"it is not ok"* would be? Edit and improve the question. Read the advice on asking in the help center.

Comment: I have one remark and some questions. First python csv deals with only **one** delimiter and you cannot use at the same time tab and comma. If that is not an option, you cannot use python csv module. Next, will each csv file have its corresponing xlsx or simply a worsheet in a (big) unique xlsx ? And will all fields be formatted as String, all as numbers, or a mix (and then what are criterias) ?

Comment: Well, each csv will have his own xlsx and it is supposed to be as for example test.csv to test.xlsx. Field supposed to be formatted as mixed cause I have in my csv string and number.

Comment: Do you know how to open folder with  csv files automaically end convert them all?

Comment: I've solved this, you only need to add condition to format into the string, you can also give other conditions :) Anyway script works just fine :)